# Does two queries, one with OR and one with IN(), have the same performance?

Tags: sql, performance

There are 2 queries:

```
select a,b,c,d from test where a=1 or a=2 or a=3
```

and

```
select a,b,c,d from test where a in (1,2,3)
```

Which one performs better?  In the table there is an index on column a.

Comment: why not just run them and see for yourself?

Comment: Because I am not sure that this not depends from row size, type of index, rows quantity etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should depend.

as you said in your comment, there are many variables.

the best way is to run some kind of explain plan for each specific query and see the difference (if there is any) on the specific database with the specific data loaded and the specific query.

stylistically, which is not the question, I personally prefer the IN clause in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

Most - if not all - query optimizers will rewrite one form to the other before choosing an execution  plan. So these two will have the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

Generally NO! The OR operator is more flexible and can be used to evaluate many more conditions than the IN operator.

While it's true that any condition using IN operator ( inclusions ) can be replaced with an equivalent one using OR operator, it isn't true the other way: there is a really big number of conditions involving the OR operator that don't have equivalent condition using the IN operator.

This means that inclusions can be better identified when using their proper operator ( IN ), instead of a more general purpose one, so that they can be efficiently elaborated.